# I have tried all the possible options to make my download attribute functional but it doesn't start downloading on browsers when I click on the link

Tags: html, attributes

I have written this code and I'm trying to download the pdf file by clicking on the link on my browser but instead of downloading, it only shows the content of the file. It starts downloading on the VS preview but not on any of my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari). does anyone know why it's not working?

```html
<body>
  <p><a href="pdf/assignment.pdf" download="assignment">download</a></p>
</body>
```

I have also disabled all my extensions. the pdf folder is located in the same folder as my html file however I also tried locating my pdf file in the same folder as my html file. I also tried different files to download and cleared my browser cache.

Comment: Thank you vey much, @KJ! Changed the setting and it worked.